# Describe the Image and kernel of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, determinant

In a problem I was given the linear transformation 
$T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
where $T$ is defined as

$$T(x)=\det
    \begin{pmatrix}
    | & | & &|  \\
    v_1 & v_2&\cdots& x\\
    | & | & &|  \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

The question asks me to describe the image and kernel of $T$ and determine their dimension. However, when I think about this I keep trying to solve the kernel equation of $T(x)=0$. I think this is infinite because so long as $x$ is linearly dependent on the other columns the $\det = 0$

Edit:

I now get that the kernel is the $\operatorname{span}(v_1, v_2, \ldots v_n)$. Do I then need to try to create a basis of that span to get the dimension of the kernel? Also, how would I go about describing the kernel? Just the span/basis of the other vectors?

Comment: Another way to state the linear dependence is to say that $x$ is in the span of the vectors $v_1,v_2,...$ since it's a linear combination of them. Can you figure out what the kernel is from there?

Comment: It’s “kernel,” not “kernal.”

Comment: Yes, there is an infinite number of solutions. Those solutions are precisely the kernel of $T$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I now get that the kernel is the span(v1, v2, ... vn). Do I then need to try to create a basis of that span to get the dimension of the kernel? Also, how would I go about describing the kernel? Just the span/basis of the other vectors?

Comment: One way to get the dimension of the kernel would be to count a minimal spanning set of the kernel, which is a basis for the kernel. The kernel is always a linear subspace and so unless it's exactly $\{0\}$ then in an infinite field like the real number or complex numbers the kernel will also be infinite.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider two cases:

- If $\{v_1, \ldots, v_{n-1}\}$ is not linearly independent, then the image is  $\{0\}$ and the kernel is $\mathbb{R}^n$.
- Now, suppose it is linearly independent, then your kernel is right, the kernel is $\operatorname{span} \{v_1, \ldots, v_{n-1}\}$. The image is $\mathbb{R}$.